# Display.getDefault().addFilter() does not work as intended for SWT.ARROW_LEFT and SWT.ARROW_RIGHT

Tags: java, swt

I have an Eclipse Plugin project written in SWT. I have added a Global listener to listen to the keys `SWT.ARROW_LEFT` and `SWT.ARROW_RIGHT`. This is done by the `Display.getDefault().addFilter()` method. This works fine most of the time. But I have a set of buttons in a panel, and when the buttons have focus, pressing the `SWT.ARROW_LEFT` and `SWT.ARROW_RIGHT` key does not trigger the appropriate event, it just traverse between the set of keys. Does anyone have an idea as how to overcome this problem ? Thanks.

```
Display.getDefault().addFilter(SWT.ALL, new Listener() {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                if ((event.keyCode == SWT.ARROW_LEFT) || (event.keyCode == SWT.ARROW_RIGHT)) {
      }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by using TransverseEvent and set the doit field to false.